# SQL Server Integer Arithmetic and Insert Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, int, decimal

I have a table that shows how many times a person replies to a survey.  The person's `id` and the `survey id` are `varchar(10)`'s.  The replied column is an `int` that is either `0` for no response or `1` for a response and `databaseId` is a `varchar(2)`.  It looks like this:

```
  personId       surveyId         replied      databaseId
    0001           1366              0             3
    0002           2243              1             1
    0003           6693              0             2
    0004           1246              0             1
    0045           2740              1             4
    ....           ....             ...           ...
```

I'm trying to get some summary statistics about the survey response rate, but running into an error when I try to `INSERT` the results into a new table.  The new table is of the format:

```
 surveyId        respRate
     1366            0.00000
     2243            0.00832
     2244            0.02377
     8875            0.01534
     ....              ...
```

where `surveyId` is `varchar(20)` and `respRate` is a `decimal(5,5)`.  When I use the following to try and insert into the new table:

```
insert into summaryTable
  (surveyId, meanrr)  
  SELECT  t1.surveyId
  ,(sum(t1.replied)*1.0 / count(replied)*1.0) meanrr
  FROM (select * from table1 
  where databaseid in ('1','2','3')) t1
  where surveyId is not null
  group by surveyId
```

I get the following error message:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 8
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

I've done some research on this and haven't found much beyond increasing the size of the target column (ie `decimal(5,5)` --> `decimal(10,10)`) but when I tried this I got the same response.

If I just try the query part without the `insert into` part it seems to work (or I just don't get the error message).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: try breaking it down more- what if you remove the division and *1.0 and just insert the sum(t1.replied)?  do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current data type `decimal (5,5)` won't allow for values of 1.  It basically means 5 total figures, all of which are to the right of the decimal point.

I'm guessing one of your rows has a 100% response rate, which would be `1.0000` and cause an overflow.

Try a datatype like `decimal (6,5)` which allows whole numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use specific casts instead of implicit side effects (`*1.0`) to convert the values, for example:

```
cast(
  cast(sum(t1.replied) as float) / cast(count(replied) as float)
  as decimal(6,5)
) meanrr
```

Comment: @JNK: Yes, that is true, that might be what's causing that specific error message. Doing `cast(1.0 as decimal(5,5))` does produce the same error.